# Oracle dynamic Schema in for loop

Tags: oracle, for-loop, dynamic, plsql, schema

How can i use a dynamic sql statement in a for loop?
I have a variable i.owner from an outside loop which represents the Schema.

```
for j in (select * from <schema>.<table>)
loop
    begin
        null;
    exception when others then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error');
    end;
end loop;
```

A cursor would cause a similar problem.

Comment: Is the table name - or at least the table structure, or the columns you query and their data types - fixed, or does that potentially change for each `i` too?

Comment: that is actually fixed and i also need only 1 varchar2-column from it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use dynamic SQL in a cursor-for loop. You have to either bulk-query into a collection, or probably more usefully use the [open for, fetch and close pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-BAC52F38-B427-4860-9B6D-336B3AEE6AD2), e.g.:

```
declare
  c sys_refcursor;
begin
  for i in (<however you get the owner/table_name now>)
  loop

    open c for 'select * from ' || i.owner || '.' || i.table_name;
    loop
      begin
        fetch c into ...;
        exit when c%notfound;
      exception when others then DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('error');
      end;
    end loop; -- j
    close c;
  end loop; -- i
end;
/
```

The problem is the `...` part - i.e. what you fetch into. If the table structure, or at least the columns you are querying, is the same each time round the `i` loop then you can define individual scalar variables to fetch each column into, or define a record variable based on the `%rowtype` of one of the tables (if they are all the same and you always have one you know exists, and you're using `select *`), or define a record with fields that natch what you're fetching.

If the structure can vary then you'll have to look at the `dbms_sql` package.

If the table name is always the same, and doesn't come from your `i` loop, that can be simplified slightly to:

```
    open c for 'select * from ' || i.owner || '.<table_name>';
```

Comment: Thank you :) works fine with "'select CR from ' || i.owner || '.MIG_TAB where status = 0 group by CR'" and "fetch c into CR"